# Add Article in Controler Asp net .core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to add `Article` from my Controller. But it doesn't work. When I use postman I receive error 500

```
ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
[Route("api/users/{userId}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ArticleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPrmRepository _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ArticleController(IPrmRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CretaArticle(int userId, ArticleForCreation articleForCreation)
    {
        var author = await _repo.GetUser(userId, false);
        //check autorization

        if (author.Id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            return Unauthorized();

        articleForCreation.AuthorId = userId;

        var article = _mapper.Map<Article>(articleForCreation);

        _repo.Add(article);

        if (await _repo.SaveAll())
        {
            //Mapp Data to return db
            var articleToReturn = _mapper.Map<ArticleToReturnDto>(article);
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetArticle", new {id = article.ArticleId}, articleToReturn);
        }

        throw new Exception("Creating the article failed on save");
    }
```

Models responsible for the model in the database:

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId{get; set;}
    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

Dtos:

```
public class ArticleForCreation
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

}

public class ArticleToReturnDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

AutomapperProfile mapping data to the database:

```
CreateMap<ArticleForCreation, Article>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Article, ArticleToReturnDto>();
```

Can someone help you understand why it does not work?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Is an exception thrown or do you see some kind of error 
message?

Comment: Please provide more details on the error that you receive.

Comment: probably just add a '[HttpPost]' on your action `CretaArticle`. can you provide how do you post data to server.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to exactly help you without the actual exception. However, the following line screams "error":

```
if (author.Id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
```

You've got a potential `NullReferenceException`, `FormatException`, and `ArgumentNullException` all from that one line.

First, neither your controller, nor action is decorated with an `Authorize` attribute and you've provided no information about the request you're making, and whether or not you're even including something like an `Authorization` header with that, nor whether you've configured authentication correctly in `Startup.cs` to utilize that, had you. Long and short, odds are that there actually is no user principal to get the claim from in the first place.

Any time you have something that could potentially be null (like the return from `User.FindFirst`), you should do a null check. That could be an actual `if` statement or ternary, a null-coalesce (`??`), or the newer null-conditional (`?.`). Otherwise, if you try to access a member off an instance that happens to be null, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` thrown. For this actually the best thing you could do is simply use `User.FindFirstValue` instead, which then removes the need to dereference the `Value` member afterwards.

Next, if the return of `FindFirstValue` ends up being `null`, `int.Parse` will throw `ArgumentNullException`, as you cannot parse `null` to an `int`. As a result, you'll need to ensure that the value is not null before you call this.

Then, if the id is not actually something that can be parsed into an `int`, like a GUID, for example, you'll end up throwing a `FormatException`. You may know it's an int, but you should always guard your code against potential changes in the future. When you need to parse a string to an int (or any other primitive type for that matter), you should always use `TryParse`:

```
if (int.TryParse(myString, out int i)
{
     // you can now use `i` as the parsed int for whatever you need
}
```

Long and short, this is a much better way to write that line of code:

```
if (!int.TryParse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), out int id) || author.Id != id)
    return Unauthorized();
```

Essentially that says if the claim value is null/can't be parsed as an int or it doesn't equal the author's id, then return `Unauthorized()`.